# How do I interpret negative SHAP values for a marketing model?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, marketing, shapley-value

I am building a marketing model to evaluate marketing channel effectiveness.  My inputs are the marketing spend for each channel, and my target variable is sales.  I have 3 years of weekly data in this format.

I used xgboost in the model so that I can use SHAP to get the relative impact of each channel on sales.  I would like to go one step further and use the SHAP values to get a weekly attribution of the sales for each channel (i.e. channel 1 contributed x sales, channel 2 contributed y sales, etc.).

However, I am running into a weird issue.  I have a lot of weeks where one or more channels has a negative SHAP value, which I can only interpret to mean that the marketing spend in that channel that week somehow lowered the sales.  This doesn't make sense to me, I would think that the worst a channel could do is have no impact on sales.  In other types of models, I know that negative SHAP values mean that the channel had a negative impact on the target variable, I just don't understand the interpretation in the context of a marketing model.  I further don't know how to get channel attribution with these negative SHAP values.

Has anyone built a model where negative SHAP values aren't interpretable in your context?  I have searched for a way to restrict the SHAP values to be positive (you can do this with the coefficients of traditional linear models), or for ways to deal with the negative values but I have come up empty.

Comment: I get annoyed by ads all the time. It’s certainly possible to have a negative effect in theory. But it could also be endogeneity. For example, sales are down so you spend additional money to boost them, which means periods with negative shocks will also have high spend. Unless you are varying spend randomly, this is quite common.

Comment: I thought about this as well, but looking at my data more closely the periods with negative shap values also have low channel spend.  I know shap has a baseline value that is the same for every week and gets added to the channel shap values to get the predicted sales for the week.  It's almost like the model is saying that the low spend in these weeks dragged the sales down lower than they would have been if you hadn't spent on marketing at all, which doesn't make sense.